# CSV data and JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, csv

Is it possible to use client side JS to open and extract (into an array) data from a CSV file located at a URL?  If so, could someone please explain how to do this, as I am struggling to work out how to use JQuery as the examples never seem to open a csv, they only use csv as a variable (with the implication that I know how to get that into the code in the first place - which I don't)

I need to get some weather data into a JS array within my browser, from which I will generate some gauges to show wind speed and direction.

My CSV is currently hosted here : http://mrmoneymotivator.com/windspeed/windspeed.csv and has some dummy data in it.

I am currently just looking at getting the first line of data for the gauges (which will be refreshed routinely).  Once I have that working, I will be using the array of arrays to display historical data in a chart.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have issues doing this as Javacript won't allow you to store files locally etc. You could probably hack a work around, but why don't you want to do anything Server side?

Comment: You'll need ajax to do this, but you'll need your javascript to be running on the same domain as the one you're targetting. if that's not the case, you'll need some server-side code to act as a proxy, as cross-domain ajax queries are tricky to implement.

Comment: @Andrew My reasoning (and I am certainly open to being told I am wrong!), for wanting it client side, is so that the routinely updating csv can be refreshed from the client browser without having to make a call to the server side.  Is this not the most efficient way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do this if the CSV and the document containing the JavaScript are served from the same *origin*. (More: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

You'd retrieve the data using an [`XMLHttpRequest` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), which will give it back to you as text. Then, depending on the complexity of your CSV data, it could be as simple as using `String#split` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) to get an array of lines (rows), and then using `String#split` again in a loop to get an array of the values for each row. I say "depending on the complexity" because CSV is a more involved format than people sometimes suspect, involving quoted cells which can contain line breaks and commas. But if your data don't use those features, just a couple of `split` calls will do the trick. if your data *do* use more features, you might need to find a library that handles parsing accoding to the [full RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Here's a complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oxuwar/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/oxuwar/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Load CSV</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
      xhr.open("GET", "http://jsbin.com/ocuqog/1");
      xhr.send();
      display("Request sent");
      
      function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 &&
            xhr.status >= 200 &&
            xhr.status < 300) {
          display("Got response");
          showData(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
      
      function showData(data) {
        var rows = data.split(/\s+/);
        var rowNum;
        var cells;
        var cellNum;
        
        for (rowNum = 0; rowNum < rows.length; ++rowNum) {
          cells = rows[rowNum].split(",");
          display("row " + rowNum +
                  " has " + cells.length + " values(s)");
          display("row " + rowNum + "'s first value is " +
                  cells[0]);
        }
      }
      
      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response TJ.  I am looking at the solution now!  I have had several people ask me why I want to do this client side, and to be honest it's only due to inexperience/lack of knowledge that is making me head to client side extracting of the CSV.  Would it actually be more sensible to grab the CSV server side, and force the client browser to refresh the whole page routinely?  Apologies if I am not articulating myself very well, when attempting something new for the first time it is often hard to actually find the right words to ask the right questions!

Comment: @DazEvans: The server has to respond either way (either with the CSV file, or a page derived from it), so it's really up to you.

Comment: Thanks TJ.  But what if the csv is hosted on another site and is being exposed via a public url?  I am beginning to think I would first need to get a copy of it on to my server, then work on the copy rather than the original?

Comment: @DazEvans: Yes, that's correct. But if that's the case, you'll have issues with a client-side approach as well, because of the SOP (unless, of course, the user is using a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)-enabled browser and the third-party server supports CORS and allows calls from your origin). But if you're doing that, it gets even more complicated, because on IE8 and IE9 you have to use `XDomainRequest` rather than `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder,  Thanks again TJ.  I am now looking at running a php page from the server side, getting the data from the csv file that I will re-download from the public URL. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ajax the CSV file

either use a library (i am sure you capable of searching for JS CSV alone :))

or

split by  '\n'  to get Rows   and  split again  by  ','   to get values ...
    NOTE : sometime CSV put values in " marks so be ready.

i use a library found at: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-csv.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
   url: "http://www.example.com/report.csv",
   cache: false
}).done(function( csvData ) {
     var arr2D = $.csv.toArrays(input);
});
</script>
```

Note: untested!