# How can I read a CSV file from a URL in a Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, async-await, next.js

I have a Next.js application [here](https://github.com/ivan-rivera/balderdash-next) which needs to read a [CSV file from a URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivan-rivera/balderdash-next/main/public/test_rare_words.csv) in the same repo in multiple places, but I cannot seem to be able to retrieve this data. You can find the relevant file in my repo [here](https://github.com/ivan-rivera/balderdash-next/blob/main/lib/vocab.js).

Note, the URL I'm trying to pull data from is this: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivan-rivera/balderdash-next/main/public/test_rare_words.csv`

Here is what I've tried so far:

### Approach 1: importing the data

```
let vocab = {};
...
async function buildVocab() {
  const words = await import(VOCAB_URL); // this works when I point to a folder in my directory, but it does not work when I deploy this app. If I point at the URL address, I get an error saying that it cannot find the module
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    vocab[words[i].word] = words[i].definition;
  }
}
```

### Approach 2: papaparse

```
const papa = require("papaparse");
let vocab = {};
...
export async function buildVocab() {
  await papa.parse(
    VOCAB_URL,
    {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      delimiter: ",",
      step: function (row) {
        console.log("Row:", row.data); // this prints data correctly
      },
      complete: function (results) {
        console.log(results); // this returns an object with several attributes among which is "data" and "errors" and both are empty
      },
    }
  );
  // this does not work because `complete` does not return anything
  vocab = Object.assign({}, ...raw.map((e) => ({ [e.word]: e.definition })));
  console.log(vocab);
}
```

### Approach 3: needle

```
const csvParser = require("csv-parser");
const needle = require("needle");
let vocab = {};
...
let result = [];
needle
    .get(VOCAB_URL)
    .pipe(csvParser())
    .on("data", (data) => {
      result.push(data);
    });
vocab = Object.assign({}, ...result.map((e) => ({ [e.word]: e.definition })));
// This approach also returns nothing, however, I noticed that if I force it to sleep, then I do get the results I want:
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(result);
  }, 1000); // now this prints the data I'm looking for
```

What I cannot figure out is how to force this function to wait for needle to retrieve the data. I've declared it as an async function and I'm calling it with `await buildVocab()` but it doesn't help.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Sorry, I'm a JS beginner, so it's probably something fundamental that I'm missing :(

Comment: TJ shows examples of how to do this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529444/4797603

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours on this, I think I finally found a solution:

```
let vocab = {};
export async function buildVocab() {
  await fetch(VOCAB_URL)
    .then((resp) => resp.text())
    .then((text) => {
      papa.parse(text, { header: true }).data.forEach((row) => {
        vocab[row.word] = row.definition;
      });
    });
}
```

The only oddity that I still can't work out is this: I'm calling my `buildVocab` function inside another async function and I noticed that if I do not include a console.log statement in that function, then the vocab still does not get populated in time. Here is the function:

```
export async function sampleWord() {
  await buildVocab();
  const keys = Object.keys(vocab);
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
  console.log(`selected word: ${keys[index]}`); // this is important!
  return keys[index];
}
```